# Forbidden You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin, centos, lamp

Hi I have installed LAMP on my centos machine and when I try to hit phpmyadmin through my browser I get this error :

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access `phpmyadmin` on this server.

My phpmyadmin.conf file has following content:

```
Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
        Options none
        AllowOverride Limit
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try create symlink  of phpmyadmin in `/var/www` or `/var/www/html` (which is your apache document root)
`ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www` or
`ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html`
 and access to it http://localhost/phpmyadmin

In new versions it's `/var/www/html`

Comment: Can you send youtube link because I don't speak english

Comment: Use this command in terminal `ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin`

Comment: I don't have this file    /usr/share/phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

If file `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` does not exist, run:

```
ln -s /usr/share/phpMyAdmin /var/www/html
```